# What Dayjs code for below moment js code?

Tags: momentjs, dayjs

What would be similar code in dayjs. As I am working in removing moment and using dayjs in big code base.

```
moment.tz('Asia/Calcutta').utcOffset()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dayjs().tz('Asia/Calcutta').utcOffset()
```

Refer
https://day.js.org/docs/en/manipulate/utc-offset